# Getting unique name for every output file (docxtpl)

Tags: python

So, I have a templator, based on docxtpl. It makes files based on csv table, which is formed automatically. The problem is - sometimes I have to create 2-3 same files, where all difference is in one parameter, so, I need a unique name for every file. But I don't really understand, how can I add a counter to the file's name?

I added a counter to the templator def, but don't really understand how to include it to the file's name (it's in `doc.save` part)

```
doc.render(context)

def create_counter():
    i = 1

    def func():
        nonlocal i
        i += 2
        return i

    return func

counter = create_counter()

doc.save(output_path / output_str.format(short_name=student['short_name']))
```

If you need, you can find full code [here](https://pastebin.com/XHhjRcmM)

Comment: you can create a function that check if a file exist with a given name, if it does add a number to and check again, repeat until a file with that name does not exist and return that new name

Comment: Please don't paste code on pastebin (it will get lost in the future, making this question pretty useless). Create a [mre] instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, everything was much easier. I just added a new column in table, where the number of document is included and added it the `output_str`.

You can find new full code [here](https://pastebin.com/0SdBUQuT).
Thanks to [@martineau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/355230/martineau) and [@Lior Pollak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/938227/lior-pollak) for answers

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

Use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
def templater(templat e_path, students):
    for i, student in enumerate(students):
        doc = DocxTemplate(template_path)

        student = middle_processor(student)
        context = {
            'first_name': student['first_name'],
            'second_name': student['second_name'],
            'third_name': student['third_name'],
            'year_number': student['year_number'],
            'course_name': student['course_name'],
            'number': student['number'],
            'form_of_education': student['form_of_education'],
            'count': student['count'],
            # 'where_is': student['where_is'],

        }

        doc.render(context)

        doc.save(output_path / output_str.format(short_name=student['short_name'], counter=i))
```

Comment: Well, I don't really understand where is counter in your variant:(

Comment: the counter is in the variable `i` from the `for i, student in enumerate(students)` that you get from the enumerate function

Answer (score 1):

I don't have `docxtpl` installed, but here's how to implement a very simple approach that ought to work. It changes `create_counter()` into a [generator function](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html#generators) instead of the factory function you have in your question:

```
from pathlib import Path

output_path = Path('output')
student = dict(short_name='Monty')

def create_counter():
    i = 1
    while True:
        yield i
        i += 1

counter = create_counter()

for _ in range(3):
    output_str = f'Справка_{{short_name}}_{next(counter)}.docx'
    print(output_path / output_str.format(short_name=student['short_name']))
```

Output:

```
output/Справка_Monty_1.docx
output/Справка_Monty_2.docx
output/Справка_Monty_3.docx
```